# Update all posts automatically within a 1hour interval

Tags: php, wordpress, wpf

I want to create a script that updates all of my published WP posts (including CPTs) automatically every hour.

I tried searching and didn't find any results about that.

Any ideas?

Thank in advance!

Comment: What do you want updating in the posts?  This may be better done when you display a post rather than some other way.

Comment: Did you check the WordPress REST API? https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/

Comment: [WP Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) may help you with the scheduling, but it depends on you having consistent traffic to your site because it only triggers when a request is made to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lack details, e.g. what data exactly you want to update.

However, you can use the WordPress REST API with the `/posts` endpoint:

```
POST /wp/v2/posts/<id>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post

(If you want to update a lot of posts, it should be done via batch request - meaning 1 request instead of x.)

Furthermore, you would need to execute a (real) hourly cron job that calls your script, but this is a whole other topic and there are a lot of howto articles in the internet.

Comment: The update post function should not add any data to the post, just press update in the set interval (an act is updated automatically upon update)

I want to update all of my posts (thousands).

Comment: This is not possible via REST API (it also doesn't really make sense, sry - updated means that sth of the post has changed). You'd have to write an SQL script to update the entries in the updated column in the posts's database table. The SQL script can be called hourly. In any case, you would fake that the content of your posts has changed - every hour! I strongly recommend not to do that.

Comment: I have to do it. I have an ACF calculation that only updates when the post is "updated".

Comment: Then I recommend you ask another question here on SO: how to get the ACF calc to update without the post being updated.